# Self removing object

Tags: javascript, object, self-reference

I'm currently creating a project in which every visible element, is represented by javascript object.

I need a method within this object, which will let me destroy it.

There's an example of that object :

```
var example = function(some_args){
    var self = this;
    var references = {}; //this holds references to inputs within given view
    this.createView = function(){
        //here I`m doing "stuff" like filling innerHTML of container
        //creating event delegate, etc.
    }
    this.destroy = function(){
        self.elements["box"].parentNode.removeChild(self.elements["box"]);  //box is a reference to container element
        self.elements = null;
        delete self;
    }
```

Now, my question is : am I doing everythig what I have to in order to COMPLETLY destroy this object?
I`m not holding any other references to objects or elements.

EDIT: 
I see that some of You do not undestand my question. 
**Barmar got it right, for which I am gratefull :)**.

I`m aware of GC, it is just easier to write "I am destroying object" than "I am removing last reference to object, so GC could take care of it" :)

To be specific. Considering that I am removing last reference to object, inside function which is part of this object - is there anything else I should take care of? Or my code is completly fine, and object will be considered as garbage?

Answer (score 1):

You don't handle lifetime of an object in JS explicitly.

So for the given question:

> am I doing everythig what I have to in order to COMPLETLY destroy this object?

the only answer is:

You cannot do that, since an object in JS can only be destroyed by a GC, which you cannot interact with. When an object is reachable - then it's alive. When it's not - then it's a "[Schroedinger's object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger's_cat)".

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a garbage collector, so you don't need to destroy the object. Also you can't

Comment: I think the point of his question is whether he's doing everything necessary to ensure that the object becomes garbage, so it can be collected.

Comment: Yeah, then I guest all references to the object must be deleted, so GC can collect the object easily. isn't it?

Comment: Read the last line of the question: he doesn't have any references to the object. He wants to make sure there are no references to it in the DOM.